# My C++ program can't print out an entity's attribute

Tags: c++

This is a simple C++ program that I made, I'm only using classes and constructors on this code. The problem here is, if I print out one of the entity's attributes, C++ would give me a runtime error where it won't print out the entity's height, weight, material or place. It just prints nothing.

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Monolith{
    public:
        int height;
        int weight;
        string material;
        string place;

        Monolith (int height, int weight, string material, string place){
           height = height;
           weight = weight;
           material = material;
           place = place;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Monolith EiffelTower(300, 10000, "Iron", "Paris");
    cout << EiffelTower.place;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you make your constructor's args const, the issue should become apparent.  you really meant to use this->place=place.  a good practice is to name all members with a prefix of m_ to avoid using the same names in another scope.

Comment: FYI, I highly recommend changing your coding style so that parameters and members have different names.  Some styles prefix members with "m_" while other styles append members with "_".  This makes reading your code easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning nothing at all, because you assign to your local variables.

Either try:

```
Monolith (int height, int weight, string material, string place){
   this->height = height;
   this->weight = weight;
   this->material = material;
   this->place = place;
}
```

or this:

```
Monolith (int height, int weight, string material, string place) :
    height(height),
    weight(weight),
    material(material),
    place(place)
{
}
```

To elaborate on what's going wrong: The problem is 'variable scope'. 'Local' tops 'class', 'class' tops 'global', in this order.

So if you have local variables that have the same name as the class variables, you need to declare your 'target scope' explicitely (hence the `this->`, which explicitely addresses the class variables). If you wanted to write to global variables, you'd need to prefix it with `::`.

The second example uses the 'initialization syntax', where you call the constructor of the named attribute with the passed item.
Prefer this syntax if applicable, because it avoids default construction.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I followed this same method on a youtube video though, and I was kinda curious why the youtuber's program ran perfectly without declaring anything or using this->, but mine is the opposite.

Comment: @TheFear If I were to wager a wild guess, I'd guess that the Youtuber either used different names or the initialization syntax. By the way, if you consider your problem as 'solved', it'd be nice, if you could click that little checkmark beneath the answer you consider 'the most helpful'. That way, anyone stumbling across your question will know that you no longer require help.

Comment: Oh thanks, sorry for the late reply lol, and also. So that's how check marks work in stack overflow, thanks for giving me another info I'm not expecting to receive. Since I'm a new user here. Again, Thank you so much.

Comment: @TheFear This site exists for the purpose of helping each other out. Who knows, in a few years time it may well be you, who helps out a newcomer to programming (and/or StackOverflow).

So yeah, you're very welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of the constructor function variables.

code:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Monolith{
    public:
        int height;
        int weight;
        string material;
        string place;

        Monolith (int height_1, int weight_1, string material_1, string place_1){
           height = height_1;
           weight = weight_1;
           material = material_1;
           place = place_1;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Monolith EiffelTower(300, 10000, "Iron", "Paris");
    cout << EiffelTower.place;

    return 0;
}
```